# React: setState is return an error in a scroll handler. What is breaking it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

When the user reaches the bottom of the page and then scrolls up, React throws the error "TypeError: _this.setState is not a function"

This is a scroll handler that checks the position of the client. If the client is in the home section of the page, it updates the state {active: 'home'}. Then, the navbar component rerenders and gives the home-navlink the class of active.

```
class Navbar extends Component {

  constructor(){

    super();

    this.state = {

    active: 'home'

    };

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);


  }

  componentDidMount(){

    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);

  }

 componentWillUnmount(){

    document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);

  }



  //offset values are location of elements minus the navbar (10vh)

  handleScroll = ()=>{

    let wind = window.pageYOffset;

    let tenVh = window.innerHeight / 10;

    let offset = {

      home: document.getElementById('home').offsetTop - tenVh,

      tech: document.getElementById('tech').offsetTop - tenVh,

      projects: document.getElementById('projects').offsetTop - tenVh,

      contact: document.getElementById('contact').offsetTop - tenVh,

    };

    if (wind < offset.tech){

      if (this.state.active !== 'home' ){ 

        this.setState({

          active: 'home'

        });

      }

    } else if (wind > offset.tech && wind < offset.projects){

      if (this.state.active !== 'tech' ){

        this.setState({

          active: 'tech'

        });

      }

    } else if ( wind > offset.projects && wind < offset.contact ){

      if (this.state.active !== 'projects' ){

        this.setState({

          active: 'projects'

        });

        }

    } else if (wind > offset.contact){

      if (this.state.active !== 'contact' ){

        this.setState = ({

          active: 'contact'

        });

      }

    }

    }

    render(){   

    return(

      <div className="navbar" >

        <div className="navbrand">  

        <a href="#home">

          <img src={brand} alt='pig brand' />

          LtP</a>

        </div>

        <div className="link-ctr">

            <a href="#home" className={

              (this.state.active ==='home')?'active':null}>Home</a>

            <a href="#tech" className={

              (this.state.active === 'tech')?'active':null}>Tech</a>

            <a href="#projects" className={

              (this.state.active === 'projects')?'active':null}>Projects</a>

            <a href="#contact" className={

              (this.state.active === 'contact')?'active':null}>Contact</a>

        </div>

    </div>
    )
    }
    }
```

Comment: `handleScroll = ()=>{` while syntactically valid is almost certainly not what you want...

Comment: Where is your `document.getElementById('home')` home ?

Comment: @JaredSmith What approach would you take? I am new to React and want to learn best practices/alternative methods. Cheers!

Comment: handleScroll () {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
this.setState = ({
      active: 'contact'
});
```

To

```
 this.setState({
     active: 'contact'
 });
```

Also the following is not needed in constructor because handleScroll is an arrow function so arrow functions don’t need manual binding

```
  this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
```

Comment: Wow, I have been pouring over this for hours and just glanced past that. Thank you so much!